# Email Contact form not sending message

Tags: ee3, email-contact-form

Running EE 3.5.16

With the following code for the contact form on a website I am not receiving the email. I have confirmed by direct email that the recipient add

```
{exp:email:contact_form
        user_recipients="no" 
        recipients="name@mydomain.com" 
        replyto="yes"
        return="/" 
        charset="utf-8"}

        <p><label for="from">Your Email:
        <input {if logged_in}type="hidden" value="{member_email}"{/if} {if logged_out} type="text" value=""{/if} id="from" name="from"  /></label></p>

        <p><label for="subject">Subject:
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" size="40" value="" /></label></p>

        <p><label for="message">Comments:
        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="18" cols="40"></textarea></label>
        <div class="clearer"></div>
        {exp:honee class="beez"}
        <input class="submit" name="submit" type='submit' value='Submit' />

{/exp:email:contact_form}
```

Comment: Does the Communicate utility in the Control Panel successfully send email?

Comment: Yes it does send correctly.

Comment: Which protocol you are using `PHP Mailer`,`SMTP`,`Sendmail`

Comment: Using PHP Mailer.

Comment: Does the EE debug or network/console tab in browser shows any error when submitting the form.

Comment: I have not seen any errors. You can try it out yourself here: https://hobblecreek.us/. It is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Might be an htaccess issue. Have you checked this: https://expressionengine.com/forums/archive/topic/199602/contact-form-not-working

Answer (score 0):

might be a stupid one, but is the email addon installed?

Comment: Not a stupid question. You have to cover all the bases. Yes. Email addon is installed and active.